# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package when trying to import from folder inside src folder

Tags: python, file, python-import, directory-structure

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
root
    src
        folder1
            file1.py
            file2.py
        folder2
            file1.py
    main.py
    .env
```

In the `main.py` file, when trying the following import statement `from .src.folder1.file1 import ClassName`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Is there something wrong with my import statement, or should I modify something in my file structure in order to get it to work?

Comment: I think removing the dot before `src` would make it work, i.e., `from src.folder1.file1 import ClassName`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/) for more information.

Comment: It depends on what your `PYTHONPATH` variable contains, and how you run your app. Both will change how imports work.